# Internet (ethernet & wifi) drops after 2-3 mins - have to continually enable/disable

Tags: networking, drivers

I have ubuntu 16.04 newly installed on a Sony VGN-N38E laptop. Odd internet behaviour. Network will show a good connection and internet will work for 2-10 mins but then suddenly drops out. Pages will say "Connecting". I can disable and enable the network adaptor which solves the problem for another 2-10 mins but the same thing happens. Same thing through both ethernet and wi-fi adapters.

Also when I try to provide the diagnostic information specified here [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) it tries to connect to github.com but fails and times out...

**EDIT** - managed to stay connected long enough to do this. Results here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23212144/

Is anyone able to help?

Here is my output from     `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`    :

```
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
Subsystem: AMBIT Microsystem Corp. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [1468:0423]
Kernel driver in use: ath5k
Kernel modules: ath5k
```

Much appreciated!

Charlie

Comment: please try downloading the diagnostic script while internet access is running fine or if this still fails download it from another computer and transfer it via thumbdrive or similar means.

Comment: Thanks @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann - done here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23212144/

Comment: Both connections failing in thew same or similar manner suggests a router than an OS/software issue.  Your wireless settings for the active AP - TP-LINK_37F8 - are bad: Use WPA2-AES only; not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: Thank you @CelticWarrior - had a play as you suggested and it sorted the problem. Many thanks!